# Access Nuxt Router in plugin

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

I've created a Nuxt plugin that is loaded in the config file with some global functions. In one function, I'd like to access the router, and push to a new route. I am getting an error that router is undefined. Can someone help me understand how I access the router here, if its not attached to the context.

```
export default (context, inject) => {
  const someFunction = () => {
    context.router.push({ name: 'route-name' } })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

Try to destruct the context then use `app` to access the router :

```
export default ({app}, inject) => {
  const someFunction = () => {
    app.router.push({ name: 'route-name' } })
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks. I didn't really understand the process of destructing the context, but I can confirm this works, as well as my solution of calling the app from the context.app.router.

Comment: it's ES6 syntax, learn more about here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Answer (score 5):

I figured this out. When using context, you can access the router, like this:

```
context.app.router
```